# Uptime report multiple users

Tags: macos, terminal, user-account

I'm not sure I understand the command "uptime"

uptime
13:58  up 5 days,  9:49, 3 users

I have 3 users detected, but I have only one user account on the Mac and no sharing enabled.

What the users actually are?

Comment: Do you have Terminal open, with several tabs maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every terminal window you have opened counts as a login. Open more terminals and type the command again and you will see how the number changes.

Comment: How does this differ from the two answers already given?

Answer (score 8):

Close Terminal.app, then open one Terminal.app window and read the manual pages for `uptime`, `w` and `who`, e.g `man uptime`, then execute each command e.g. `uptime`, `w` and `who`in that order in that one Terminal.app window you opened.

It should become apparent however if not... There are always at least two users logged in, *you* using `console` and note its time, it's corresponds to the time you logged into your account from the GUI, and *you* using `ttys000` (the Terminal.app windows that you opened). In these instances *you* is as shown in the output of `who am i`.

Each additional Terminal window you open will show as another *user* using , e.g. `ttys001`, `ttys002`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The 'who' command lists logged-in users. You will probably find that they are multiple copies of yourself; one for each terminal window and one for the "console" session.